# Confusion about the right verb to use with 'if' and 'would'

Tags: subjunctives

I need to check the grammaticality of the following sentence:

> If I *_*_ a doctor, I would serve the poor.
>   (a) am
>   (b) had been
>   (c) were
>   (d) was

I am confused with *were* and *had been* since there is *would* in the sentence, too.

Comment: Here's an editing hint for future questions: If you put **two** blank spaces at the end of a line, then the text will be displayed with a line break.

Comment: Please don't post the same question in identical form to [multiple SE sites at the same time](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/132574/28567).  It's considered abusive, and it makes us even less likely to want to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> If I am a doctor, I serve the poor.

(Present, does not know if he is a doctor)

> If I had been a doctor, I would have served the poor.

(In past, implies he was not a doctor)

> If I were a doctor, I would serve the poor.

(No specific time, implies he is not a doctor)

> If I was a doctor, I served the poor.

(In past, does not know if he was a doctor)

Comment: Your last sentence sounds rather unusual to me.

Comment: @snailboat The poor fellow has amnesia and has forgotten his calling; but he is confident that he was always as benevolent as he is today. It's not a situation that arises often, but if it happens to you you will now know how to express it :)